# Can factory pattern be used for only one user defined class and no subclasses

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

I am trying to implement a basic factory pattern for a class which is user defined. For example a class of currencies which allows the user to enter the currency name, exchange rate, etc. Reason being that I would like to allow the possibility for future sub classes to be added.

**I do not want to create a subclass for each possible currency as the details are entered by the user and these currencies may also be ficititous. I also do not have any other classes.**

For example this is my code in which the user is expected to fill in the parameters of the class for a currency to be created. This is all done in a seperate class and they are placed in a list:

```
public String code;
public String name;
public boolean major;

public Currency(String code, String name, boolean major) {
    this.code = code;
    this.name = name;
    this.major = major;
}
```

I think I must be missing something but I cannot figure it out. It is possible that the factory pattern is not supposed to be used in this manner?

This is my first time using this design pattern as well in conjunction with dependency injection.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can we see your attempt at a factory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the [static factory method](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA5&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) and not the [Factory Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), i.e you probably only need this,

```
private Currency(String code, String name, boolean major) {
    this.code = code;
    this.name = name;
    this.major = major;
}

public static Currency of(String code, String name, boolean major) {
    return new Currency(code, name, major);
}
```

You would need a factory design pattern if some of these are true:

1. You have a complex construction logic.
2. You have an interface and at run time you want to return a particular implementation which you select based on some logic.
3. You want to control the life-cycle of the returned object.

IMHO, unless you want any of the above and simply want to just construct an object based user input, static factory method is all you need.

Comment: Shouldn't the `public` method be `static`?

Comment: The code is not right for Java. Don't you need a `new` somewhere?

Comment: My bad, mixed up two things. Fixed it now